# Is there a way to create an HTMLElement, which will delete itself later?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have an abstract class "Component"

```
abstract class Component {
    protected container: HTMLElement;
  
    constructor(tagName: string, className: string) {
      this.container = document.createElement(tagName);
      this.container.className = className;
    }
  
    render() {
      return this.container;
    }
}
```

Other classes extend this class. Is there a way to make `render()` return a `this.container`, which later will be deleted from DOM, i.e. after 5 seconds?

Comment: When do you want the 5 seconds to start? When you construct the class (i.e., the element is created)? Or when it is rendered (presumably when it is attached to the DOM)? Your code never adds the element to the DOM, BTW.

Comment: Yes, this one does not add to the DOM. It returns node which is added later. I want the coundown start since it is added to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `setTimeout`?

```
abstract class Component {
    protected container: HTMLElement;
  
    constructor(tagName: string, className: string) {
      this.container = document.createElement(tagName);
      this.container.className = className;
    }
  
    render() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.container.remove()
      }, 5000)
      return this.container;
    }
}
```

Comment: @DanyilDerkach This will not do what you asked for; The countdown here starts from the call to `render()`, not necessarily when it is added to the DOM. A user of `Component` could call `render()`, and then 4.5 seconds later, add it to the DOM, making the element only appear for half a second...